# How can I edit a long URL in the Safari browser on my iPad 2?

Tags: ios, ipad, mobile-safari, url

I'd like to be able to edit a long url in the Safari browser on my iPad 2 running iOS 8.1.1. I can select it, but I can't scroll through it to add or delete something on the end. I generally copy/paste it into Notes, do the edit, then paste it back into the browser window, but that's a number of steps and becomes tedious.

Is there a way to do that type of edit inside the browser window?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hold down your finger in the address bar to get the little magnifier to show up, finally drag your finger to the right or left to get to the part of the url that you want to edit.

**Update** In recent versions of iOS, for devices with force touch, the address bar is selected, you can force touch the keyboard and slide your finger left and right to move the cursor.

**ReUpdate** Thanks for pointing out @Decade Moon, that in even more recent versions of iOS, you can hold the space key on the keyboard and move your finger left and right to move the cursor.

Comment: It does not work on an iPhone 6s.

Comment: It appears that with more recent versions of iOS you need to tap in the address bar to get focus, then tap again and hold to get your cursor.

Comment: You needn't use force touch on the keyboard, you can also tap and hold on the space bar.

Comment: Lifesaver @DecadeMoon !!! This has been bugging me for YEARS.